# ASP.net MVC - How to bind and empty dropdownlist to a model on change?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've two drop down lists on a view. Upon selection in the first list, I'm dynamically populating the second list using ajax call:

```
$('#NonSelectedCourses').change(function () {
        console.info(this.id.toString());

        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $("#lstSections").html(procemessage).show();

        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        console.info("List: " + this.id + " Item: " + option);

        //Retreive list for new selection
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/Layout/GetSectionFromCourses")' + '?id=' + option;
        console.info("AJAX Url:" + url);
        $.ajax({ url: url, success: SectionDataRetrieved, type: 'GET', dataType: 'json' });
        });
```

And a function to populate the other list on successful operation:

```
function SectionDataRetrieved(data) {            
        var ddl = $('#lstSections');
        ddl.empty();
        $(data.sections).each(function () {
            $(document.createElement('option'))
                .attr('value', this.Value)
                .text(this.Text)
                .appendTo(ddl);                
        });
    }
```

and a dropdownlist to be populated:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sectionList, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Select Sections --", new { id = "lstSections" })
```

Now, how can I send the data back to the controller. I'm aware of sending it through the Ajax call, but is there a way to bind it back to the ViewModel and send it.

Comment: The value you select will be bound to you `sectionList` property when you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the name attribute of the DropDownList that will be read by the model binder and bind it to your ViewModel, you just need to match the name attribute of your DDL to your ViewModel property name.
Say for example you have a `Section` property in your ViewModel then you can set  the name attribute like below:

```
SectionDataRetrieved(data) {            
    var ddl = $('#lstSections');
    ddl.empty();
    ddl.attr('name', 'Section');
    $(data.sections).each(function () {
        $(document.createElement('option'))
            .attr('value', this.Value)
            .text(this.Text)
            .appendTo(ddl);                
    });
}
```